# use object in my queries @query java spring

Tags: java, spring, dao

I get an error when I tried to reference an object in my query

```
@Query("select o from Account o where o.ownerId=:owner AND o.name like :#{#customer.name}") public List<Account> findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUserById(@Param("owner") String owner,@Param("customer") Customer customer);
```

Error message :

```
No parameter binding found for name customer!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parameter binding found for name customer!
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your Account and Customer pojos?  Not sure if its intentional but you're comparing your account name with customer name.

Comment: Remove `@Param('customer')`. You don't have a query parameter `:customer` so obviously that isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this.

```
 @Query("select o from Account o where o.ownerId=:owner AND o.name like CONCAT('%',:customer.name,'%')") 
 public List<Account> findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUserById(@Param("owner") String owner,@Param("customer") Customer customer);
```